# Is there a way to parallelize Pandas' Append method?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have 100 XLS files that I would like to combine into a single CSV file. Is there a way to improve the speed of combining them all together?

This issue with using concat is that it lacks the arguments that to_csv affords me:

```
listOfFiles = glob.glob(file_location)
frame = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, a_file in enumerate(listOfFiles):
    print a_file
    data = pd.read_excel(a_file, sheetname=0, skiprows=range(1,2), header=1)

    frame = frame.append(data)

# Save to CSV..
print frame.info()
frame.to_csv(output_dir, index=False, encoding='utf-8', date_format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: A work around suggestion, you could merge all the csvs and load into Dataframe, instead of loading them seperately

Answer (score 3):

Using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), you could read them in parallel using something like:

```
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd

dfs = multiprocessing.Pool().map(df.read_excel, f_names)
```

and then concatenate them to a single one:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

---

You probably should check if the first part is at all faster than

```
dfs = map(df.read_excel, f_names)
```

YMMV - it depends on the files, the disks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be more performant to read them into a list and then call `concat`:

```
merged = pd.concat(df_list)
```

so something like

```
df_list=[]
for f in xl_list:
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(f)) # or read_excel

merged = pd.concat(df_list)
```

The problem with repeatedly appending to a dataframe is that the memory has to be allocated to fit the new size and the contents copied and really you only want to do this once.

Comment: Is that possible we can parallel the process to append an integer, not a data.frame?